# How to exit a TensorFlow session with a queue runner

Tags: python, tensorflow

Say I have defined a function that loads one label/features pair from a TfRecords file as follows

```py
def read_one_image(tfrecords_path):

    queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([tfrecords_path])
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    key, value = reader.read(queue)
    features = tf.parse_single_example(value,
        features={'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
                  'image': tf.FixedLenFeature([784], tf.int64)})
    label = features['label']
    image = features['image']
    return label, image
```

Fetching the images in a session works fine if I keep the session open:

```py
tf.reset_default_graph()

label, image = read_one_image("mnist_train.tfrecords")

sess = tf.Session()

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)

for i in range(10):
    one_label, one_image = sess.run([label, image])

print(one_label, one_image.shape)
```

However, if I use a context manager like so

```py
g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default():

    label, image = read_one_image("mnist_train.tfrecords")


with tf.Session(graph=g) as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)
    for i in range(10):
        one_label, one_image = sess.run([label, image])

    print(one_label, one_image.shape)
```

I get an error: `7 ERROR:tensorflow:Exception in QueueRunner: Attempted to use a closed Session.(784,)`

Maybe I am misunderstanding how the queue runner works, but since I called the `sess.run` method, it should have fetched a data pair 10 times. Now, is there a way to quit/exit/close the session without exhausting the queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to the [`tf.train.Coordinator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Coordinator)

```
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Now, I only get an "info:"` INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <class 'RuntimeError'>, Attempted to use a closed Session.` I think that's normal because I didn't exhaust the queue?

Comment: it's because queue is still running. you can stop the threads using `coord.request_stop()` and `coord.join(stop_grace_period_secs=0.05) ` inside the session scope.

Comment: thanks, that solves the issue. Thanks a lot for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: sure! glad to help!

Comment: @Sebastian - btw I had reported this - see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10256